# Statement of purpose: how important is correctness of grammar and punctuation?

Tags: graduate-admissions, united-states, statement-of-purpose

English is not my first language, and I am concerned that my statement of purpose might contain some grammatical and punctuation mistakes that neither Microsoft word nor I can see. What is the best way to overcome this problem, and to what degree does this affect the admissions committee decision putting into consideration that English isn't my first language?

P.S. I don't have any native English-speaking friends and I don't trust companies or online sites to see my statement of purpose to check its correctness.

Comment: Okay, so basically I will need the help of an English language expert, but how can I make sure that my work will not be taken advantage of?

Comment: professionals, by definition, will consider any material submitted to them as confidential… I think you're worrying way too much about this, as the commercial value of your document is probably close to zero

Comment: A statement of purpose has no commercial value except for someone who would be applying to the same grad school at the same time. You're not writing a research proposal.

Comment: @aeismail and with the same background… if your statement of purpose could fit anyone, there is something wrong with it :)

Comment: @F'x♦ My statement of purpose can be modified and with the removal of two paragraphs, then it could fit a large pool of prospective graduate international students who might want to continue their highr education in the US

Comment: @aeismail so basically my statement of purpose currently (since I am applying to universities now) is valuable!

Comment: No, that's a sign that your statement of purpose is improperly written. A statement of purpose should be specific to you, in that it describes your experiences and motivations, and outlines what kinds of problems you want to solve. It also talks about the department in which you want to enroll, and how your interests dovetail with their research. If, as F'x says, your document can fit anybody, then it's not a very good statement of purpose!

Comment: If you are at a university, there might be centers on campus which specialize in such things (in case you are more willing to trust an on-campus center than a company or website).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the written question above is a genuine reflection of your English spelling and grammar abilities, then I strongly suggest you seek professional services to assist if you are in any way concerned about your abilities having an adverse impact on your application.

This application is clearly a very important step in determining your future, and if it is so important and you have concerns, it is not worth leaving it to chance. If you have no suitable friends, use a professional service. Plenty of other *native-English* speaking applicants who are competing for spaces with you will have done so.

I can't say for certain how a selection committee will factor your English as a second language. It is likely to depend on the institution and the course you are applying for.

Comment: can you please explain you first sentence in your answer, does my question show any English grammatical errors?!

Comment: Wow, native English speakers really use professional editing services?  Seems like a gray area to me...

Comment: @TheHiary - Yes, your question contains a number of errors, albeit minor, but errors nonetheless. Some of these errors, in fact, Microsoft Word would probably pick up and offer to correct for you. Your reply above also contains errors. Please don't take it too critically, but if I'm not mistaken, you'd like your application to be as close to perfect as possible, wouldn't you. If you can't trust a professional editing service, who do this type of thing by the hundreds for a living, how will you ever trust the institutions you are applying to?

Comment: @DnuorgSpu - You'd better believe it!

Comment: @long if the institution I am applying to offers this kind of service I will be more than happy to ask them for help, anyhow thank you for your answer

Comment: @TheHiary - That you are seeking advice from the outset is a great sign of your enthusiasm and drive. I sincerely wish you the best with your applications.

Answer (score 3):

English not being your first language should not be an excuse. No one is perfect and making a mistake is acceptable, surely if  you're not a native speaker. But it makes you look less interested if there are a lot of mistakes in your text.

A native English speaker would be advised - since they might be able to phrase something better than someone who's just "good".