# Would having some flaws in a perfect English SOP be bad?

Tags: graduate-admissions, statement-of-purpose, language

I have my native friend who is willing to check my SOP. I just have added a part to present the reasons why I want to pursue in department X. Unfortunately my friend is on their vacation and I don't want to bother them. The rest of the SOP is already written and proofread. Of course I will proofread it myself, but in case I cannot find any mistake, how would this be bad if I just submit this SOP?

My TOEFL writing score is 23 btw.

Comment: Can you proofread this question and find anything wrong?

Comment: I just add some bit, hope it's better now

Comment: You probably need someone to proofread your SoP again. I am not a native English speaker. But I know there is something wrong with your question text. If you have more than one friend proofreading your SoP, you should have said friends, not friend. If you had only one person proofreading it, you should have said him (or her). Based on this observation, I suggest you to find someone proofreading your SoP. You don't want a bad one.

Comment: @scaaahu I use the singular they intentionally. It's acceptable for native speakers.

Comment: I suggest OP to close the question. The question is impossible to answer without reading OP's SOP, but you shouldn't post your SOP because it would become a shopping question.

Comment: You almost certainly need someone to proofread it again. In the current question I can see at least 4-5 errors/awkward phrases that a native speaker would hopefully catch and fix.

Comment: Do you have a deadline that makes you want to submit before your friend has finished their vacation?  Or are you asking just to not bother them/get it out of the way?

Comment: @Kimball I have a soft deadline. It recommends me to submit soon because I can get a privilege to have a financial support

Comment: @YuxinZhou I don't see why this question should be closed. In a perfect English SOP, a suddenly flaw will make the native speaker notice immediately. What I ask is when that notice appears, will it makes a bad impression on me?

Comment: @RogerFan if you are in the committee, when you see a perfect SOP in English then the last part is written like this question, how would you react?

Comment: @Ooker I think any mistakes would affect my judgement at least a little. I'm not sure how much though, and I suspect many would consider it a minor thing if the rest of the application is strong. Though in [this article](http://psychology.unl.edu/psichi/Graduate_School_Application_Kisses_of_Death.pdf), spelling/grammar errors and poor writing are listed as two of the graduate application "kisses of death" (see page 21).

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/14203/19607 (situation is different, but answers should be about the same)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the survey [Kisses of Death in the Graduate School Application Process](http://psychology.unl.edu/psichi/Graduate_School_Application_Kisses_of_Death.pdf) by Drew Appleby and Karen Appleby:

> According to several respondents, spelling and grammatical errors **found anywhere** in the application are an immediate Kiss of Death.

My job should finish here, but I want to summarize the paper after a quick skim. 5 major Kisses of Death are:

1. **Damaging personal statements**: personal mental health, excessive altruism, excessive self-disclosure, and professional inappropriateness.
2. **Harmful letters of recommendation**: undesirable applicant characteristics, letters from inappropriate sources
3. **Lack of program information**: not researching the general focus of the program, not exploring how the applicant’s research interests fit the focus of the program.
4. **Poor writing skills**: spelling and grammatical errors, poorly written applications
5. **Misfired attempts to impress**

Thanks Roger Fan for linking this survey.